# How to detect and align tilted images after cropping

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have implemented a cropping algorithm on my solution that works pretty good. The problem is when the image is tilted, the crop will work but it will have background space showing as the images will show.

Cropping flow:

First step:

[image: 1st step]

Second step:

[image: 2nd step]

Final result:

[image: Final result]

I have searched/tried multiple solutions but could not get a decent result or I'm not thinking the right way.

The expected result is this:

[image: Expected result]

**EDIT [FINAL RESULT]:**

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def order_corner_points(corners):
    # Separate corners into individual points
    # Index 0 - top-right
    #       1 - top-left
    #       2 - bottom-left
    #       3 - bottom-right
    corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
    top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
    return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

def get_image_width_height(image):
    image_width = image.shape[1]  # current image's width
    image_height = image.shape[0]  # current image's height
    return image_width, image_height

def calculate_scaled_dimension(scale, image):
    image_width, image_height = get_image_width_height(image)
    ratio_of_new_with_to_old = scale / image_width


    dimension = (scale, int(image_height * ratio_of_new_with_to_old))
    return dimension

def scale_image(image, size):
    image_resized_scaled = cv2.resize(
        image,
        calculate_scaled_dimension(
            size,
            image
        ),
        interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA
    )
    return image_resized_scaled

def rotate_image(image, angle):
    # Grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # Compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

image = cv2.imread('images/damina_cc_back.jpg')
original_image = image.copy()

image = scale_image(image, 500)

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
screen_cnt = None

# loop over our contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        screen_cnt = approx
        transformed = perspective_transform(image, screen_cnt)
        break

# Draw ROI
cv2.drawContours(image, [screen_cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

(h, w) = transformed.shape[:2]

if (h > w):
    rotated = rotate_image(transformed, 90)
else:
    rotated = transformed

cv2.imshow("image", original_image)
cv2.imshow("ROI", image)
cv2.imshow("transformed", transformed)
cv2.imshow("rotated", rotated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

To align your image after cropping, we can we can use a [perspective transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html). To begin, we separate the four corners of the rectangle into individual points given to us by `cv2.approxPolyDP()`. We reorder the points into a clockwise orientation (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left) using this function:

```
def order_corner_points(corners):
    # Separate corners into individual points
    # Index 0 - top-right
    #       1 - top-left
    #       2 - bottom-left
    #       3 - bottom-right
    corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
    top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
    return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)
```

This function gives us the the bounding box coordinates of the ROI

[image]

Now with the isolated corner points, we can obtain the transformation matrix using `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()` and actually obtain the transformed image using `cv2.warpPerspective()`.

```
def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))
```

Here's the result

[image]

We can rotate the image with this function

```
def rotate_image(image, angle):
    # Grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # Compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))
```

The final result after rotating:

[image]

Full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def order_corner_points(corners):
    # Separate corners into individual points
    # Index 0 - top-right
    #       1 - top-left
    #       2 - bottom-left
    #       3 - bottom-right
    corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
    top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
    return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

def rotate_image(image, angle):
    # Grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # Compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

image = cv2.imread('1.PNG')
original_image = image.copy()

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
screen_cnt = None

# loop over our contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        screen_cnt = approx
        transformed = perspective_transform(original_image, screen_cnt)
        break

# Draw ROI
cv2.drawContours(image, [screen_cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

# Rotate image
rotated = rotate_image(transformed, -90)

cv2.imshow("image", original_image)
cv2.imshow("ROI", image)
cv2.imshow("transformed", transformed)
cv2.imshow("rotated", rotated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, im sure that will be super helpfull, can you tell me how to convert 4 points to a count so i can use your code ? I have this:  cv2.rectangle(image, (best_box[0], best_box[1]), (best_box[2], best_box[3]), (0, 255, 0), 1) but i need to pass a countour perpective_transform function

Comment: Hello, again, i think i got it :) Can you see my edit and check it if it looks good and maybe suggest some optimizations ? Thank you again.

Comment: Also, does this code takes perspective of the doc and its correction ? If not, it is hard to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking for the minimum and maximum u and v positions where an edge was found (or maybe certain quantiles) to find the cropped rectangle. That is go over all image pixels that were marked an edge and update the u/v/ min/max values.

If if the computation time is not an issue for you, you can simply keep the algorithm as is and additionally loop over a number of rotations and update special values for each. Pseudocode:

```
for v
  for u
    if (u,v) is edge
      for rotation_matrix
        (ur, vr) = rotation_matrix * (u,v)
        update boundary for given rotation matrix
```

In the end you can select the bounding box for the rotation matrix that is the smallest.

If the above algorithm is too slow for your use case, you can also try extracting the major axes using the opencv [HoughLinesP](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlinesp) function. This will of course not work for all types of images, but may be good enough for the case of id cards.

Finally, to apply the rotation correction refer to [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html) tutorial.