# How to train data using tensorflow ocr?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to tensorflow, so i am little bit confuse in tensorflow there are multiple model to perform OCR like

1. attention_ocr
2. street

I have below document which i have to perform OCR. I tried to use `pytesseract` to read image but not giving proper result.
[image]

I need below result from above image

- **D MANIKANDAN**
- **DURAISAMY**
- **16/07/1986**
- **BNZPM2501F**

Please suggest me please tensorflow modal is useful to perform above OCR.  I am using below code to get data from `pytesseract`

```
def getData(coordinate, image):
    (y1, y2, x1, x2, classification) = coordinate
    ts = int(time.time())
    height = y2-y1
    width = x2-x1
    crop = image[y1:y1+height, x1:x1+width]
    CROP_IMAGE_URL = EXPORT_PATH +"data.jpg"
    cv2.imwrite(CROP_IMAGE_URL, crop)
    img = cv2.imread(CROP_IMAGE_URL)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    os.remove(CROP_IMAGE_URL)
    return text
```

Comment: People who down voted please comment for the reason of downvoting.

Comment: I have not downvoted but I guess you should post code also (what you have tried so far)

Comment: where you are facing the problem detecting the text right? If yes, then config your pytessearch by choosing `psm` and `oem` value

Answer (score 2):

**Steps:**

- Detect contours.
- After extracting ROI based on contour, extract your text using tesseract.

---

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

img = cv2.imread('pan2.jpg')
image= img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(blur, 0,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Dilate to combine adjacent text contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,2))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours, highlight text areas, and extract ROIs
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
ROI_images = []
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if area > 1000 and 12<h<18:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        ROI = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        # cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1
        ROI_images.append(ROI)
plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(dilate)
plt.subplot(133)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

---

```
for i in ROI_images:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(i,config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
    print("text:",text)
    plt.imshow(i)
    plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: You have to adjust     `if area > 300 and 7<h<20: `

Comment: I have seen your other example images also. If you use above condition. You will also get `income tax department, govt. of india, permanent account number` etc but you can discard them right? by using regex or simple string matching to extract the text you want.

Comment: is this code will work for all type of images like this https://new-img.patrika.com/upload/mediafiles/2017/07/06/l_pancard-farzi-1499313521_835x547.jpg

Comment: Dexter If you want to make it general then you have to crop only PAN card and transform it to make it straight which can be done using oopencv.

Comment: ohk..means i have crop image to pan card after that i have to get text from that crop image

Comment: It's working for the above url image also but you will end up getting other text also. So if you want to generalize it then crop only pan card and transform it.

Comment: There can be plenty of cases right. in some of the cases Pan card can be tiltted a bit or it is captured from far. So you have to remove the background and only get the pan card and transformation will be also required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459002/how-to-detect-and-align-tilted-images-after-cropping
This will help you.

Comment: Can you help to write all code in one file first align image after that get text from that image i tried whole afternoon but not able to get it done :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212262/discussion-between-dexter-and-pygirl).

Answer (score 1):

First you must create an object detection model to find the region of intrests as shown in the picture. Then you can pass the ROI image into the OCR model or PyTesseract.

[image]

Comment: I have done the same thing but sometime PyTesseract giving garbage words..that y i have to do in proper tensorflow

Comment: Did you config your pytesseract?

Comment: Thats one of the major problem with PyTesseract. I used Azure Read API Service for the OCR part which gives really accurate results