# Remove Background from contours

Tags: python, opencv

I am having some problem with removing unwanted contours.

Image with detected contours:

[image]

I do not want the following contours as shown in this image (the area marked in blue color):

[image]

But I cannot seem to get rid of them. 
My code:

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

edges = cv2.Canny(img, 240, 240)
#cv2.imshow('', edges)


thresh = cv2.threshold(edges,150, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
cnts, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Show and Write Threshold Image
#cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
#cv2.imwrite('Thresholded_labeled_image.jpg', thresh)

# Find and Draw Contours
contours, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img_contours = cv2.drawContours(thresh, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('contours', img_contours)

# Remove Noise
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
dst = cv2.filter2D(img_contours,-1,kernel)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img_contours),plt.title('Image_Contours')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Averaging')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

I tried morphology:

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow('closing', closing)
```

I tried changing the size of the kernels but it still doesn't work. I still see those unwanted contours.

Is there anything I could try to do?

Edit 1: Using boundingRect

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,2))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours, highlight text areas, and extract ROIs
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
ROI_images = []
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print("Area is: ", area)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    print("Height: ", h)
    if area > 100 and 0<h<300:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        ROI = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        # cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1
        ROI_images.append(ROI)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Then try to filter the contours by length and area properties.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I haven't done this before.

Comment: I mean you will be getting so many numbers of contours right?. You can remove them by creating threshold. Like if a contour  area  is more than this, turn into black (no object)

Comment: So using,  area = cv2.contourArea(contours), I can find the areas and then removing unwanted areas? Or makign all these pixels black (0,0) ? Correct?

Comment: Yes you can also get `x,y,w,h` from using `cv2.boundingrect()` just create your own threshold condition.

Comment: This is how you filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61358554/6660373

Comment: I vote boundinrect instead of contour length

Comment: @Pygirl When I tried using the code mentioned in that link you shared, I do not get any image at all. Maybe I am doing something wrong but I changed the value of area and height. But I am still unsure what area and height I should select. Currently I have, area>100 and 0<h<300. Please check Edit 1 for the output I am getting.

Comment: I will say print area and w,h for all the loops before making some conditions.

Comment: yeah, I did that and the result I got was, area = 139129.0 and height = 374

Comment: Wait actually thing is some of the contours will be too small so you can remove them based on their property. size, length, aspect ratio etc. The answer I provided you was just to show how you can select those contours. and then I crop those contour part which is not required in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do. You have to edit the below code as per your requirement.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('try.png')
img_res = img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)
contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)
# area_list = []
for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
#         print(area,w,h)
        if area<5200:

            img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = (255,255,255)
            cv2.rectangle(img_res, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

### Original_image

**try.png:**

(Here I have loaded it as RGB image, you have to modify your code to find out the contours)

[image]

### Detected contours to remove

**img_res:**

[image]

### Final result

**img:**

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. It worked and hence I have accepted the answer,  But, Can you please explain me why have you taken parameters 1, 2 in findContours() function ?

Comment: there are three arguments in cv.findContours() function, first one is source image, second is contour retrieval mode, third is contour approximation method.

See this: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Comment: Okay Perfect. I always used (cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) these two arguments. Good to know. Thanks for your help!